# PHP - Repeat and append a variable to a calculation

Tags: php, string, variables, repeat

I am trying to create a script that takes a `$$variable` and adds them to each other a number of times (based on another variable) - `$total`

This script is part of a much larger script that contains a few SQL queries and loops, hence the `$$value` as opposed to the usual `$value`

My current (static) script is like so:

```
$$value = ($$value + $$value + $$value + $$value + $$value);
```

This will work if I continue to modify the number of `+ $$value` within the brackets but I need it to auto calculate and ammend itself so that it always writes the correct number of `+ $$value`

I have tried using `str_repeat()` but it only fetches the first value of the `$$value` variable and then repeats that value (not grabbing the next value and so on). I have also tried creating a loop, which also didn't work.

I need something that will look at `$total` and from that number produce something similar to the following:

```
$$value = ($$value * $total)
```

The above will multiply the numeric value of the `$$value` and therefore not return the result I want.

Can anyone help?

Many thanks,

Tom

Pastebin Link to my script: http://pastebin.com/7Qg02hWB (in the pastebin, `$$valu`e is `$$ob_id` and `$total` is `$o_total`)

Comment: Could you write an example with `$$value` content ? I'm not sure to understand what you want to do.

Comment: I think you should consider using a clearer syntax, like `${$value}`

Comment: Any time you encounter a situation where you need to use variable variables, you should consider rethinking your strategy.

Comment: @JBRTRND http://pastebin.com/7Qg02hWB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you mean, but how's

```
$foo = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) $foo .= $$value;
$$value = $foo;
```

This will loop over $total times and concatenate it. If you're having problems like it's adding it as an integer for some reason you could always do a cast like `(string) $$value`. I know you said you tried a loop but we have no code so it could have been a problem with your code.

Answer (score 0):

this?

```
perhaps you need powers?

$total = 5;
$$variable = 2;    // random value; and why i have two 2 $$ ?
for($x=0;$x<$total;$x++) {
   $$variable += $$variable;
}
echo $$variable;

OR,

$total = 5;
$$variable = 2;
echo "<br>POWER of 2^$total: ".pow($$variable,$total);
```